# Getting error of "error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object'. "

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, mongodb-query

> error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object'.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user = new BehaviorSubject<Userlogin>(null);
  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,private http:HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  loginClicked(form:NgForm)
  {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    const login = { email :email,password:password};

    //alert(password);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3007/api/signin',login).subscribe(responseData => {
      console.log(responseData);
      if(responseData.user.name)
    {
        this.handleAuthentication(responseData.user.email,responseData.user._id,responseData.user.name);
        this.router.navigate(['/main']);
      }
    })
    form.reset();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `any` to bypass TypeScript type check:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3007/api/signin',login).subscribe(responseData: any => {
```

Better practice is to use a custom type or interface you create for the response data.